# Custom SonarQube rule to find unused using directives

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to write a custom rule using SonarQube C# to find unused using directories. I tried using `SyntaxNodeActionUsingDeclaration` but no use.

Comment: Are you writing your rule as a Roslyn analyzer (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/) or as a SonarQube custom plugin using Java (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/adding-coding-rules/)?

Comment: I am using below repository and trying to extend.
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube-roslyn-sdk

Comment: So the first step is to write a standalone Roslyn analyzer. The tooling in the sonarqube-roslyn-sdk repo just wraps your Roslyn analyzer in a Java plugin that can be consumed by SonarQube. Do you have your Roslyn analyzer working correctly as a "standalone" analyzer i.e. so that is working in Visual Studio / MSBuild?